# Find hidden form values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find out why, when I try to explore website in chrome I see variable. But when use get from request, this one value gone and I don't know why.

This one below is from "Chrome":

```
<ul id="topMenu" class="clear">
<li class="login flyout">
<div class="divider divleft">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="#" id="loginBoxOpener" title="Logowanie">
<span>Logowanie</span>
</a>
<div class="divider divright">&nbsp;</div>
<form id="login" name="login" action="https://shop.murrelektronik.pl/index.php?" method="post">
<div id="loginBox" class="loginBox" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="stoken" value="88ED0243">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="14">
<input type="hidden" name="actcontrol" value="start">
<input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="login_noredirect">
<input type="hidden" name="cl" value="start">
<input type="hidden" name="pgNr" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="CustomError" value="loginBoxErrors">
<div class="loginForm">
<h4>Logowanie</h4>
<p>
```

Later I was use:

```
login_user = self.req.get(self.url_login)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(login_user.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.contents)
```

And get from this part:

```
<ul class="clear" id="topMenu">
<li class="login flyout">
<div class="divider divleft"> </div>
<a href="#" id="loginBoxOpener" title="Logowanie">
<span>Logowanie</span>
</a>
<div class="divider divright"> </div>
<form action="https://shop.murrelektronik.pl/index.php?lang=14&amp;" id="login" method="post" name="login">
<div class="loginBox" id="loginBox">
<input name="lang" type="hidden" value="14"/>
<input name="actcontrol" type="hidden" value="start"/>
<input name="fnc" type="hidden" value="login_noredirect"/>
<input name="cl" type="hidden" value="start"/>
<input name="pgNr" type="hidden" value="0"/>
<input name="CustomError" type="hidden" value="loginBoxErrors"/>
<div class="loginForm">
<h4>Logowanie</h4>
<p>
```

In this option I lose variable "stoken", but I need this to hold session when try to log into webstie :(

```
<input type="hidden" name="stoken" value="88ED0243">
```

Some one have same problems maybe? :(

Edit 03.08.2020   12:12
And what if I need to use POST first because then I get "stoken" then I create my "Form Data" with session_stoken. Then I POST again with "login_data" and still not logged in.
Value in cookies: SID  when I read in every step (POST, GET and POST is always this same.
So I Think its session active but still not logged.

Comment: Edit: when i use only request this variable is visible. After using "soup" it's gone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked on the website and I think I've found the solution.

When you make a GET request you get neither the cookies or the `stoken`.

To get both of them you simply make a POST request and retrieve the session cookies.

Every time you make the requests with those cookies, the `stoken` value will not change.

```py
r = requests.post('https://shop.murrelektronik.pl/index.php')  # `stoken` available
cookies = r.cookies   # extract cookies

# extract `stoken` value
stoken_value = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')\
                    .find('div', {'class': 'loginBox'})\
                    .find('input', {'name': 'stoken'})['value']

# Fill in the data (note: I have not checked the actual fields' names)
data = {'username': 'JohnDoe', 'password': 'p@ssW0rD', 'stoken': stoken_value}

# login request
r = requests.post('https://shop.murrelektronik.pl/index.php', cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

That should let you login into the website.

Comment: Hm ok, I changed fields names for username as "lgn_usr" and password as "lgn_pwd".

Comment: Hm ok, I changed name fields for a username used "lgn_usr" and password, "lgn_pwd". We have a button "submit" there, that it tells me that need use in my POST method always link from "action" field?   I make this but still, I'm not logged in to website.   After POST login data and cookie from session. SID this same before and after its okay. Can't understand what wrong with login POST. Form data which is sent to the website is okay, but still, something missing here :(

Comment: I do not quite understand what your problem is.
The form data (`data` field in the `requests.post` method) must look like the data sent from your browser to the page. [Here](https://imgur.com/lFcWrNh) is what I get in the post request when I try to login.

Comment: This what You tell me is corrent. I send this data in requests.post. This step in Your code and mine is the same. But after line with POST method, I'm trying to read website, because I don't know during executing POST method, that is everything okay. Then I'm trying to get prove with GET method, but from this I've prove, that still not logged in :( And here is my problem, because I send message to server, without any feedback with problem or error code.  Something like walk in the dark heh :) Sorry for me, I know I'm "noob" for now, but try learn how to do this well :)

Comment: When you try to "read the website" (presumably with a GET request) do you include the cookies in the GET request?

Comment: I understand like this:  requests.post make data frame which is send to server by link. But in source of this website are scripts in javascript I guess. It's run too? But by server then we POST data?  And I'm think about widgets on this website, there must be some token which tell to website which widgets are visible after login? :/

Comment: JS scripts are not run. If you want to interact with the page like you do in your browser then you must use a package like `selenium`.
Regarding the second part, the "token" that tells the website that you are logged in is the cookie itself. This is why you must include it in every request you make, so that the server knows that's you who is making the requests.

Comment: Yes, I include the "cookies=cookie" in get requests.   About JS scripts, I use request on: "https://shop.murrelektronik.pl/index.php" website. When some links to JS scripts files are written in code on this main site, server did not run this? JS script I see run widgets in main window. So maybe I'm logged in, but can't see data which is visible after login, because widgets are not visible and I'm thinking im not logged in? :(

Comment: Try saving the `r.text` (HTML from response) in a .html file and see what it looks like. 
This way you can see if the content you want to scrape is actually loaded by JS or not.
If what you need is not present on the local HTML page, then your task can't be solely completed by `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Then my task can't be solved this way :(  I'm using beautiful soup always to read data on website to get some prove, that I'm logged in. And from the beginning wasn't see this data :( But didn't know I can't get it solely by requests and BeatifulSoup. I just thought I've problem with login and can't go in :/

Comment: Thank you for your time anyway. You taught me a lot :) Discussion I think best way to learn :)  In my case website can't show interesting me data without reload js script and widgets, so I go try other way :D